# Java Play WS.get does not process url properly?

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

In java Play (2.3.9) application trying to get absolutely correct url:

```
WS.url("http://foo.dfg?q=" + URLEncoder.encode("text with = sign", "utf-8"));
```

get this: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: QueryString parameter should not have more than 2 = per part

digging the code revealed that there's a code deep inside NingWSRequestHolder:

```
if (reference.getQuery() != null) {
   this.setQueryString(reference.getQuery()); //getQuery returns already decoded query
}

public WSRequestHolder setQueryString(String query) {
    String[] params = query.split("&");
    for (String param : params) {
        String[] keyValue = param.split("="); //param == "q=text with = sign" here
        if (keyValue.length > 2) {
            throw new RuntimeException(new MalformedURLException("QueryString parameter should not have more than 2 = per part"));
        } else if (keyValue.length >= 2) {
            this.setQueryParameter(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
        } else if (keyValue.length == 1 && param.charAt(0) != '=') {
            this.setQueryParameter(keyValue[0], null);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(new MalformedURLException("QueryString part should not start with an = and not be empty"));
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Shouldn't line

```
String[] keyValue = param.split("=");
```

read:

```
String[] keyValue = param.split("=", 2);
```

Am i missing something or it is a bug?

Comment: I actually need this, the encoding multiple key value pairs on one parameter, to circumvent the 22 params limit of the Playframework (Scala Tuple22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

I am aware of two options how to construct a proper URL:

```
WS.url("http://foo.dfg").setQueryString(yourQueryString);
```

and

```
WS.url("http://foo.dfg").
    setQueryParameter(param1, value1).
    setQueryParameter(param2, value2);
```

Do you get the same result/exception with both invocations?

Also, keep in mind the note [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html):

> The URLEncoder and URLDecoder classes can also be used, but only for HTML form encoding [...]

---

Your query string is `q=a=b=c=d` - this already has more than two `=`.

A query string like `page=2` would return an array with length two and thus will be marked as *correct*.

As you can see from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the default `limit` parameter is zero. Zero means the pattern will be applied as many times as possible. This is why you get more than two split parts.

The proper way to provide a query string goes like this:

`param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3` and I believe this is how you should reformat your string. Note how in this case you have multiple parts but each consist of only one key and value (thus only one `=` in between)

Comment: It is not what i need. I need to pass a string which potentially can contain equals sign. Before i encode this text with URLEncoder.encode.
So the url looks like "http://domain/path?q=text_with_%3D_sign" which is perfectly legal. Once it gets to setQueryString the parameter is already escaped: q=text_with_=_sign ant it leads to RTE

Comment: I updated my answer with more information. Maybe this will give you some hints...

Comment: Thanx, Anton, looks like setting query params separately from url does solve the issue, though it is somewhat confusing. If method "get" accepts url as string why absolutely correct url leads to RTE?